# Multiprocessing - memory consumption

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I've read all the related posts on the subject, but I can't for the life of me get multiprocessing to work properly with shared memory.

I'm using an EC2 instance with 96 cores, but for some reason despite using shared memory, my memory consumption explodes when using a worker pool with 96 workers.

EDIT: Had a bug earlier, which caused not all the cores to be used (stupid bug where I didn't give the right parameters for map) - anyways, clarified my current problem.

Any ideas? Attaching a screenshot of htop on my server to show the CPU usage + memory consumption.

[image]

For reference, I used the figtree package from here: https://github.com/ec2604/figtree (commit - 7ba197e45a5c6577fab56d469b4b1ccf02242e3d), it's a forked repository that ports C level code to python. Don't think it should really matter, you can plop any CPU intensive code in there instead.

!!!!!!EDIT!!!!: In hindsight, the figtree package allocates memory for the result (50000*9995*8) / (1024**3) GB per process. If you multiply that by 96 processes this is what causes the insane memory consumption.

```
import figtree
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import ctypes
from multiprocessing import Pool, sharedctypes
n = 50000
m = 9995
X_base = sharedctypes.RawArray(ctypes.c_double, n* 77)
X_shared = np.frombuffer(X_base.get_obj())
X_shared = X_shared.reshape(n, 77)
X_shared[:] = np.random.normal(0, 1, (n, 77))
del X_shared

Q_base = sharedctypes.RawArray(ctypes.c_double, m** 2)
Q_shared = np.frombuffer(Q_base.get_obj())
Q_shared = Q_shared.reshape(m, m)
Q_shared[:] = np.random.normal(0, 1, (m, m))
del Q_shared


def fig_helper_efficient(slice):
    print(id(Q_shared))
    Q_shared = np.frombuffer(Q_base)
    Q_shared = Q_shared.reshape(9995, 9995)
    X_shared = np.frombuffer(X_base)
    X_shared = X_shared.reshape(n,77)
    if Q_shared.shape[0] == Q_shared.shape[1]:
        res = figtree.figtree(**{'X': X_shared[slice, :], 'Y': X_shared,
                                 'Q': Q_shared[:, slice].copy(), 'epsilon': 1e-12,
                                 'h': 15})
        print("done")
    return res

def divide_batches_equally(num_examples, num_batches):
    div_result = num_examples // num_batches
    mod_result = num_examples % num_batches
    size = np.zeros((num_batches + 1, 1)).astype(np.int32)
    size[1:] = div_result
    if mod_result > 0:
        size[1:mod_result + 1] += 1
    return np.cumsum(size)


def parallel_fig_vert_efficient():
    n_proc = 96
    size = divide_batches_equally(m, n_proc)
    parallel_list = [slice(int(size[i]), int(size[i + 1])) for i in range(n_proc)]
    with Pool(n_proc) as pool:
        res = pool.map(fig_helper_efficient, parallel_list)
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parallel_fig_vert_efficient()
```

Comment: An oversight on my part, problem is still happening though after fix. Edited.

Comment: Maybe over-subscription of CPU resources could be an issue? `multiprocessing` calling third-party numerical libraries can wreck havoc with threads. How many threads are spawned?

Comment: How many threads or how many processes? Not sure regarding threads, but 96 processes (as the amount of CPU's)

Comment: One theory: when you do reshape, you may create a copy of the array. That would require some memory. Can you try to run this without reshape (without doing calculations) - just 'sleep' - and see if the issue persists?

Comment: FWIW, I do not think it is correct to create the arrays at global scope. When importing the module in a subprocess, Python cannot know the arrays are meant to be the same - it just sees the instruction to construct a new one. [Protect them with the ``__main__`` guard, as shown in the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.synchronized)

Comment: Tried just commenting the figtree.figtree part and it didn't consume memory. @MisterMiyagi - Tried that as well, memory consumption still exploded.

Starting to suspect figtree.figtree is allocating memory.